# Are there any statistic/analytic apps for Django?

Tags: django, analytics

I'm looking for a Django app that can collect stats for display to my users - i.e. how many views/clicks/interactions a user has had on an object they own - tracking over time etc. Similar to how you can view stats for your flickr photos and so on.

Or is there a service out there that can collect this info and be used to display it back to my registered users?

EDIT:

Or how about a simple app that logs stuff like so -

`stats.log_action(my_object, stats.VIEW)`

`stats.log_action(my_object, stats.CLICK)`

This would then simply store the action + the object, along with the DateTime. Working with a Generic Foreign Key relationship... We could then get aggregate results and display them how we liked... I think for now, this should be the way -

So... is there anything out there that does this? Or should I roll my own?

Thanks,
Guy

Comment: removed the comment! added it to the question!

Comment: What did you end up using for this?

Comment: we just built our own very simple app to handle this.

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of stats/analytics apps out there. I have not tried any but you should find what you're looking for on [djangopackages.com's **list of "analytics" apps**](http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/analytics/)